# debuild -S in cronjob: how to avoid interactive gpg

Tags: packaging, cron, gnupg

I would like to build and submit a package to a launchpad Ubuntu reposiory of mine in a nightly cronjob. To this end, I'll have to

```
debuild -S
```

the package which by default requires human interaction since the `gpg` key used for signing is protected by a password.
The cronjob then also fails with an error message of the type

```
cannot open /dev/tty
```

which `gpg` typically uses for the password challenge.

How would I have to set up the system to work around such issues?

Comment: Why not just use launchpad's daily-build feature?

Comment: I'll try out https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/SourceBuilds.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters you'll need to get the passphrase to your `gpg` process somehow. You can use any of the following:

- **`--passphrase-fd`**
  Read the passphrase in through a file descriptor
- **`--passphrase-file`**
  Read the passphrase in from a file
- **`--passphrase`**
  Specify the passphrase directly

After that, you'll also want to add **`--batch`** and **`--no-tty`**. See the gpg man page for more explanation.

Comment: Are those options to `debuild` as well? `gpg` is never invoked directly.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't realize you weren't calling `gpg` directly (not familiar with `debuild`). A quick google search on debuild & gpg gets some hits, but I don't have more time to look into it right now. Let us know what you figure out!

Answer (score 1):

`debuild` uses `debsign` to sign. According to [debsign manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/debsign.1.html), the option `-pprogname` can be used to change the command for signing. So you can use something like this so gpg will not ask for passphrase:

```
debuild -S -p"gpg --batch --passphrase PASS --pinentry-mode loopback"
```

Change "--passphrase PASS" with your preferred way of passing passphrase to gpg.